# WithStore: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined (pure-react-carousel)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, carousel, pure-react-carousel

I use `pure-react-carousel` library and try to navigate to specific slide by `onClick` method of my Button.

Please explain me  how to use `setStoreState` because I tried to do it by myself (as written in docs) and whole my page where I used it just invisible. I tried to use `this.props.carouselStore.setStoreState({ currentSlide: 2 })`.

When I add export withStore my page become invisible. and I get following error.

```
Error is Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
my export
    export default WithStore(MyComponent, state => ({
        currentSlide: state.currentSlide,
      }));
```

Comment: The error means that somewhere in your code, you have `x.state`, where `x` is undefined. The most likely cause is you using `this.state` but the context isn't bound properly.

Comment: state is from the function calllback not the component state

Answer (score 3):

I am actually an author for Pure React Carousel.

`WithStore()` only works if it is a child of `<CarouselProvider />`

WithStore accesses React's context API. CarouselProvider creates the context. When you create a context, React only passes the context down to child components of the component that created the context.

So, the use of WithStore in this pseudo-code example will give you the error.

```
<YourComponentThatUsesTheWithStoreHOC />
<CarouselProvider>
  // all your buttons, slides, dots, etc...
</CarouselProvider>
```

This will also give you that errod.

```
<CarouselProvider>
  // all your buttons, slides, dots, etc...
</CarouselProvider>
<YourComponentThatUsesTheWithStoreHOC />
```

This pseudo-code example will work

```
<CarouselProvider>
  // all your buttons, slides, dots, etc...
  <YourComponentThatUsesTheWithStoreHOC />
</CarouselProvider>
```

Comment: I am also facing the same error  "WithStore: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined (pure-react-carousel)
", can you explain more in details to fix this issue, please.

Comment: Any component that uses WithStore must be a descendant of CarouselProvider.  Meaning, it must appear in the DOM somewhere between the CarouselProvider tags for your carousel.

Answer (score 0):

The Parenthese are unnecessary. Try this:

```
export default WithStore(MyComponent, state => {
    currentSlide: state.currentSlide,
  });
```

Comment: It doesn't work I get error  after this - in browser failed to compile